# Problem with ACF Loop table checkbox (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I'm busy with an WordPress website and use Advanced Custom Fields plugin. Having a problem with made a table, so there are option which are true or false. I will add an screenshot of the result I have so far.

Here is the current code:

```
        <div id="abonnementen-table">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Specificaties</th>
                <?php foreach($abonnementen as $abonnement){?>
                <th><?php echo $abonnement->post_title;?></th>
                <?php }?>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $field = get_field_object('uitgebreide_specs',$abonnement->ID);
        $choices = $field['choices'];
        foreach ($choices as $choice_value => $choice_label){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $choice_label;?></td>
                <?php
                foreach($abonnementen as $abonnement){
                    $values = get_field('uitgebreide_specs',$abonnement->ID);
                    $field = get_field_object('uitgebreide_specs',$abonnement->ID);
                    $choices = $field['choices'];
                    foreach ($values as $value) {
                        if ($value['value'] == $choice_value) {
                            echo '<td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <?php }?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

The problem is of the code above if it is checked it works good, but if the option is unchecked there is an problem. The screenshot will show you my problem:

[image]

I have tried to put an else at this point:

```
if ($value['value'] == $choice_value) {
    echo '<td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>';
} else {
    echo '<td></td>'; // unchecked
}
```

But then I have too many columns - see screenshot below. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Mind sharing $values and $choices?

Comment: I think that there is one foreach loop too much, so I think that is a nice plan to combine them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So maybe if you can provide an export of your ACF fields, I can provide a better answer. But nonetheless, how about adding the unchecked `td` like so:

```php
$_td = 0;
foreach ( $values as $value ) {
    if ( $value['value'] == $choice_value ) {
        echo '<td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>';
        $_td++;
    }
}
if ( ! $_td ) { // add it if a TD hasn't been echoed
    echo '<td></td>'; // unchecked
}
```

Or a simpler version using `array_column()` with `in_array()`: (this would replace the entire `foreach ($values as $value) { ... }`)

```php
$values = array_column( $values, 'value' );
if ( in_array( $choice_value, $values ) ) {
    echo '<td><i class="fas fa-check">Y</i></td>';
} else {
    echo '<td></td>'; // unchecked
}
```

I hope those help?